# How to disable Year/Month navigation in Bootstrap DatePicker

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

I'm tryng to disable the month/year navigation button on the bootstrap datepicker.

I want to disable the ability for users to click on the "Month/Year" text in between the navigation arrows and can't figure it out.

[image]

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to restrict users to only use the arrows you can use the `maxViewMode` option

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    maxViewMode: 0
});
```

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/zcvq0yhh/17/

Comment: It doesn't work in my project. I have done the same of your example but i can't understand why it doesn't work!

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle example with your setup? And which version of the datepicker do you use?